# Expand variable in the bash script to pass its value in the single quotes

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have written following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ff in $(ls *.mkv *.mp4 *.avi); do
    echo Processing $ff
    php -r 'echo ph_dct_videohash("$ff");' 
done
```

But instead of expected substitution of $ff with its current value in the `php` line I am getting error:
`PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: ff in Command line code on line 1`. Looks like `$ff` have been passed as is but not as its expansion. How can I achieve to pass expansion of `ff` instead of `$ff`?

Comment: no need to `ls`: just say `for ff in *.mkv *.mp4 *.avi`

Comment: @fedorqui thanks for note, but the question was not about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `'echo ph_dct_videohash("'$ff'");'`.

(`'$ff'` is literally `$ff`, but `"$ff"` and `$ff` expand to the value of the variable `ff`).

Update. A more correct approach (for names with whitespaces):

```
for ff in *.mkv *.mp4 *.avi; do
    echo "Processing $ff"
    php -r 'echo ph_dct_videohash("'"$ff"'");'
done
```

`'echo ph_dct_videohash("'"$ff"'");'` will always expand to one argument for `php`, and adding `$` characters to the PHP code would not cause additional shell variable expansion (because of `'...'`).

Comment: `php -r "echo ph_dct_videohash('$ff');"` may be better to handle filenames with spaces

Comment: Filenames with spaces will be broken anyway after `ls` here, but generally you are right (a simple test shows it: `a='1 2'; for f in '['$a']'; do echo "$f"; done` produces two lines, `[1` and `2]`).

Answer (score 1):

You aren't passing a variable; you are attempting to dynamically construct a PHP command, which has all sorts of problems and security risks.

To actually pass a value to PHP as a argument, use something like

```
for ff in *.mkv *.mp4 *.avi; do
    echo "Processing $ff"
    php -r 'echo ph_dct_videohash($argv[1]);' "$ff"
done
```

(My knowledge of PHP itself is a bit lacking; you many need to adjust my PHP code, but the *call* to `php` should be correct.)

Answer (score 0):

just undo the quotes just before the `$ff` evaluation and resume them afterwards, like this:

```
php -r 'echo ph_dct_videohash("'$ff'");'
```

This won't work as-is if the filenames contain spaces. Other answers have addressed the "don't use output of `ls`" by using directly wildcards in `for`. I won't paraphrase those.

Comment: Leaving `$ff` unquoted is a bad idea.

Comment: you're right. edited for correctness, but no need to copy the existing better answers.